# Two Columns with two different full-width backgrounds in the same container and row on Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello Bootstrap Experts!

Currently, I am doing a web project. But I am feeling stuck to create a section. The section has two columns with two different full-width backgrounds in the same row. How can I make it? Here is the screenshot of the section from PSD https://ibb.co/mN4AU7

Regards

Answer (score 1):

I divided full view port into two part by using bootstrap row and column. Now you can insert your bootstrap carousel in first column and insert your form code in second column.

```css
div img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      height: 100vh;
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <!-- INSERT HTML CODE FOR CAROUSEL-->
          <img src=https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff&text=insert+carousel+here>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 p-0">
          <!-- INSERT HTML CODE FOR FORM -->
          <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/ffffff/fff&text=insert+form+here">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, I am doing the project with Bootstrap 3. Will it be a problem if i use Bootstrap 3 instead of 4? Also please explain you used some JSplugins in here?

Comment: No, there will be no problem in using Bootstrap 3. But it is always suggestible to use latest version of any technology and framework. I did not use any JS plugin, these are CDN import to use to Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, why did you use these lines <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hi, I have tried it by your way. But I want the content in container area not container-fluid area. Because my other sections are in container class not container-fluid. Is that possible?

Comment: I copied all the links from [Bootstrap Page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/) BTW you only need other two libraries if you are using Bootstrap compiled javascript.

Yes you can change container-fluid to container. Container-fluid expands to full width of view port but container have some padding it will not take full width of view port.
You can also change your container to container-fluid.
If you want to know more you can read from [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/overview/#containers)

Comment: It's not the perfect solution. I want full-width backgrounds. Thanks btw

Comment: Container taking full background width you can check [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMzgWL).This is what you want. Try to read more bootstrap docs.

Comment: Hi, I have seen your codes. You used two images with graphics content instead of the background images. Also, you changed the default behavior of container and row it should not be. Here is what happens when i tried to follow your solutions https://codepen.io/AsadItDev/pen/QmXMbb

Comment: This is small problem of overflow. If you don't want to change the behaviour of container make a new class with width 100% and put the class in div containing container class. [check this]( [Check This](https://codepen.io/tonystark007/pen/YaoxNd)).

Comment: Hi Tony, Maybe you did not understand my issue accurately. I want full-width backgrounds and also I want to put the content under Bootstrap Container (max-width:1170px).

Comment: Sorry, I am not able to understand what do you want. Maybe you can give me your email address or something so we can discuss it more clearly